# Can I use the same object more than once in foreach loop

Tags: php

Here I am writing the code fully to explain my problem. the links are generated but the list is not.
what could be the problem? thanks..

```
require 'database.php';
$query="SELECT subject.subjectName, subject.subjectId FROM course,subject where subject.subjectId=course.subjectId                                                        
                      and course.memberId=1";
$courses=$db->query($query);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>foreach</title>
</head>
 <body>
<?php foreach ($courses as $course):?>
              <a href="#">
               <?php echo $course['subjectName'];?>
            </a>
             <br>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
    <ul>

     <?php foreach ($courses as $course):?>
              <li>
               <?php echo $course['subjectName'];?>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
     </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Small comment to clarify you are not using objects in this particular situation. Knowing the correct terminology for PHP can help other people here solve your problems.

Comment: @TomKriek: `foreach` twice would not cause an issue unless `$courses` is no longer in the scope on second iteration. I suspect he's either out of scope, or `$courses` actually implements `ArrayAccess` and `Iterator` and makes a mess of it. Need more info.

Comment: @TomKriek doesn't this create an object ?       $courses=$db->query($query);

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the source code and make sure the UL is actually empty - maybe some strange CSS behaviour is hiding the elements from you

Comment: @Barakzai If you include your source code from the start then we can see what's actually going on.

Comment: @TomKriek I have included the full source code for the page please take a look if possible.. thanks

Comment: @Barakzai Will see if I can find the mistake. And to be clear `$courses` and `$course` aren't an object.

Comment: What is your expected output and what results are you getting at the moment?

Have you tried printing the `$courses` array on screen and see what is actually in it?

Answer (score 1):

Your second code has a quote inside before the closing PHP tag.

Before

```
<?php foreach($courses as $course):?> <a href"<?php echo $course['courseName'] "?> </li> 
<?php endforeach;?>
```

After

```
<?php foreach($courses as $course):?> <a href="<?php echo $course['courseName']; ?>">???</a> 
<?php endforeach;?>
```

And for easier to read code

```
<?php
   foreach($courses as $course) {
      echo '<a href="'.$course['courseName'].'">A Link</a>';
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, foreach does not modify the object. You are probably overriding $courses variable between two foreach blocks

Comment: No the only place I am using $courses is in foreach loops and it perfectly works when i make a copy of $courses as $courses1 and use it in second foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Just not sure if its mistake while type code here or you have exactly same code in your script but pls check this in second for each

Here you are missing "=" after href should be like this
 is missing

Answer (score 0):

Did you check page source? It might be hidden by css as you have different HTML tags in each block

Comment: I have not used any CSS . the same code works if I make a copy of $courses and use it as $courses1 in the second loop..

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone I finally got the answer for my problem and here it is:

In my code $courses is a PDOstatement Object and foreach loop calls upon fetch() method and fetch() method frees the result set, that means at end of foreach loop there are no more rows left. its all freed, so we can not use the same $courses again in loop since there is nothing left in it...

hope I am not missing anything ...